# how to install linux leaveing my data intact

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, debian

greeting ,

here is what I wanne do in a nutshell , 
I hava 2 partitions c:/ and d:/ 
and I want to install the latest debian as dual boot with windows 
basically I want to shrink my c:/ drive
and give debian a 50 ~ 100 GiG >> ( 1 - Is that enough )
problem is :
after I shrink my c:/ or d:/ drive  leaveing about 100 g for the installation 
I dont want to lose any data I dont really fully understand the partitioning method 
so , 
It would be great if any one could help my out ? 
thanks ..

Comment: This is an Ubuntu forum. Although Ubuntu is based on Debian, the installation process and the user interface to install Ubuntu is totally different. If you need help with Debian, see here http://www.debian.org/support . Ubuntu can be downloaded from here http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Answer (score 1):

Based on this post: http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html

Just boot your computer with Latest version of Ubuntu (current is 14.04 LTS), follow the install instruction.

At partition screen, choose **Something else** and install Ubuntu to free partition.